# When should I use "all in"?

Tags: formality

I learned that "all in" is an informal way to say exhausted. Is it more common to say "I am exhausted" or to use "I am all in"?

Comment: I've never heard "all in" used that way, so it can't be too common (though I see it in the dictionary.) *I'm exhausted, I'm totally wiped (out), I'm done in* I've heard. Maybe it's British? Or very regional?

Comment: I've heard "all in" used exactly this way, but mostly from persons of British extraction, who also say "fagged out" in the same way.

Comment: I'd say that one should avoid using "all in" (in this sense) until one is comfortable saying it.  There are plenty of alternatives that are less likely to be messed up somehow.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It's a perfectly ordinary usage in BrE, as is the equivalent ***done in***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't say it wasn't "perfectly normal".  But for someone not quite comfortable with the language there is a definite danger of the term being understood as having one of its other meanings, since context is quite important in this case.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I understand that if you were simply *told* someone at a poker game said *I'm all in*, you wouldn't know whether they'd staked all their available funds (and were thus bound to at least stay and see out the current hand), or were exhausted (and were thus likely to leave). But if you were actually in that game, the intended sense would always be obvious. Just as if he'd said *I'm shot*, context would always make it obvious whether he was exhausted, or had been hit by a bullet. There's no reason to "avoid" such commonplace usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Whatever.  It was just advice, to avoid being misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of "**all in**" OP asks about seems to be a British articulation which I cannot speak to. For what it's worth, while the idiom appears to have originated as a *poker* metaphor, contemporary usage in AmE of "**all in**" (which, in my experience, no longer seems to connote with exhaustion) has expanded well beyond poker and is now applied (*especially in sports*) to any contested situation whose resolution involves the investment of time, energy, and material resources. "**all in**" means **TOTAL COMMITMENT**, unreserved and without limitation. [**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all+in)

Comment: +1. This is the sense I'm familiar with. Never heard it being used to mean exhausted.

Comment: That’s a different meaning than the one asked about, though.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - good lookin out, I've amended. Did you get my 'ping' of thanks for yesterday's lesson in 'anaphora'? :-)

Comment: I don’t think I saw that, no—but I’ll consider myself pinged. :-)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Could it be that you didn’t get your bell rang because I added the acknowledgment and gratitude within the body of this answer, [**and so's my wife**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257734/and-sos-my-wife/257745#257745)?

Comment: Yes, that would be it—pinging only works when commenting and only when you ping someone who ‘exists in the thread’ (i.e., the person who asked the question, the person who wrote the answer you’re commenting on, or someone who’s commented on the same question/answer that you’re commenting on). If I tried pinging Brian Hitchcock (who commented on Jonatan’s answer below) in a comment to your answer, he wouldn’t see it, either.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - ahh! More thanks are in order.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You might consider yourself _pung_, thus contributing to a potential Google stats on newly emerging irregular English verbs.

Comment: @anemone I did actually seriously consider writing _pung_, but decided against it at the last minute!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Lots of hack value, I think.

Comment: @anemone - I rather liked, 'punged.'

Comment: @LittleEva Sorry to butt in like this. I'm always reading stuff I shouldn't, thereby missing all the hot posts of today :))

Comment: It's all good @anemone, I'm prone to the same ... and sleeping only exacerbates the issue. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

all in
 1. Tired; exhausted.
 2. Games Staking all of one's chips, as in poker.
 3. Putting all of one's available resources into an effort: The governor mounted a half-hearted campaign for the presidency but didn't go all in.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+in

Comment: Yes, but I would just say that for definition #3, ***all out*** is far more common.

Comment: Also this amswer makes no attempt to address the actual question. It wasn't about whether "all in " _could mean_ "exhausted", but rather about whether it is more common/idiomatic to use "exhausted".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, by giving the definitions you can give the idea when to use the expression:

1) When you're exhausted: "I'm all in, guys. Count me out!" 
    When you look someone exhausted: "You look all in... get some rest."

2) When you play poker: "I bet all in..."

3) when you do your best stint, example aforementioned.

And I add:
4) When you say "all inclusive": "The flight cost me 200 pounds, all in."

Comment: Excellent. Perhaps you could add those examples to your answer.