# and so's my wife

Tags: grammar

> I'm tall, and so's my wife.

I looking for some way of understanding this kind of *and so* construction. Is it equivalent to the following?

> I'm tall, and tall is my wife.

You could say, alternatively:

> I'm tall, and my wife is tall.
>   I'm tall, and my wife is also.
>   I'm tall, and also my wife is. (maybe???)

So why is the 'is' moved before 'my wife" with the *and so* construction?

Comment: +1, I thought I had understood this, but now I'm looking at *"Tom would be tall, and so would be his wife"* . . . hmm . . . :)

Comment: *I'm tall, and **my wife is so** too*. Don't ask me why you have to explicitly include ***too*** in that version (whereas the *so = also, additionally* sense seems to be carried along with *so = that [same] way* in the "standard" form). You might want to check [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22john+and+that+man+is+so+too%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for more on the usage.

Comment: I'm Brian, and so's my wife!

Comment: Sorry, @Andrew, the name's taken, and so am I.

Comment: @F.E. Is that actually grammatical to you (outside of highly archaising language)? It isn’t to me. Most naturally, I would repeat only the auxiliary; at a stretch, I would repeat _be_, but **after** “his wife”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, the thing was, I had just been spending a bunch of time on inversion (i.e. subject-dependent), and I was rather tired, and so, when I read the OP's example, I sorta automatically wanted to verify that subject-aux-inversion was being used, not subject-dependent inversion. And then, whoa, the sub-dependent inversion sounded okay but the so-called obligatory subject-aux *"and so would his wife"* sounded awkward!? Though, maybe it was because my ear was misparsing it due to tiredness, but I"m not sure.  (cont.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  (cont.) There's possibly various factors involved, and one is that verb group of two auxiliaries (which sometimes has BrE vs AmE differences). Interestingly, the *"and so would his wife be"* is awkward to me (at the moment).

Comment: In the example *"Tom is tall, and so is Sue"* (similar in grammar to the OP's example), the "so" would be considered to be the **connective adjunct** version of "so"; and also, that due to following the connective "so", that **subject-auxiliary inversion** is obligatory (according to H&P CGEL, pages 786-7). As to why this must be so, er, er, maybe that would be related to helping the hearer differentiate the different types of constructions that use different types of "so"? maybe. Perhaps someone might have a rainy day to dip their toe into this tricky, and possibly lengthy, subject. :)

Comment: @F.E. I agree that “and so would his wife be” is at least a bit awkward—but it's certainly a lot less awkward than “and so would be his wife”. That is actually only, in practice, parsable as meaning something quite different (though also fairly stilted-sounding), as in “A woman who would have married him already, and so [=therefore] would be his wife”.

Answer (score 5):

---

In the construction "*I'm tall, and **so**'s my wife*," **so** is an *anaphor*; **so** refers back to **tall**. The construction is equivalent to, "*I'm tall, and [**tall**] is my wife*."

---

> In linguistics, anaphora is the use of an expression the interpretation of which depends upon another expression in context (its antecedent or postcedent) ... The term anaphora denotes the act of referring, whereas the word that actually does the referring is sometimes called an anaphor (or cataphor).
>
> **Anaphora** (*endophora*)
>
> **a**. Susan dropped the plate. It shattered loudly. - The pronoun it is an anaphor; it points to the left toward its antecedent, the plate
>
> **b**. The music stopped, and that upset everyone. - The demonstrative pronoun that is an anaphor; it points to the left toward its antecedent, The music stopped.
>
> **c**. **Fred was angry, and so was I**. - The adverb **so** is an **anaphor**; it points to the left toward its antecedent, angry.
>
> **d**. If Sam buys a new bike, I will do it as well. - The verb phrase do it is anaphor; it points to the left toward its antecedent, buys a new bike.
>
> [**Wikipedia, *anaphora***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics))

---

*Thank you, Janus Bahs Jacquet*

---

Comment: So that's what an anaphor's for

Comment: To add a tiny bit to explain the inversion:  the anaphor *so* used in this way is usually pre-posed (put before the verb), I expect to draw attention to it, and such pre-position tends to force the subject to be post-posed.  So says https://english.stackexchange.com/a/315103 .